# GWT SerializationPolicy error when handeling an WebServiceException

Tags: java, gwt, glassfish, jax-ws

I have a project that I am working on, which unfortunately is horribly undocumented. After working out a few annoying bugs, i got it to compile and deploy on glassfish, but now I keep getting a GWT error, preventing me to see what is wrong.

WebModule[/AgentWSGui]Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call 
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException

Type 'javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized. at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.StandardSerializationPolicy.validateSerialize(StandardSerializationPolicy.java:83) at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:591) at .....

This is where the exception is coming from

```
public AgentScenario getAgents() throws InvalidAgentConfiguration, JAXBException
{
    DirectoryFacilitator    df;
    AgentScenario           as;

    as = null;

    df = AgentConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration().getDirectoryFacilitator();
    as = AWSTypeConverter.convert(df.getAgentScenario());

    return as;
}
```

and this is the gwt file

```
    <module>

<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
<entry-point class='net.sf.istcontract.aws.gui.client.AWSGui'/>
<servlet path="/awsgui" class="net.sf.istcontract.aws.gui.server.AgentGUIServiceImpl"/>
<stylesheet src='KitchenSink.css'/>
```

GWT is an old version, because it still uses the gwt-dev-windows.jat standard. I am stuck here, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if your entity class is serializable i.e you mentioned extends Srializable and you have added in your applicationcontext.xml.
if it doesn't resolve the problem , just debug and c which line exactly is giving the error just see the values of the variables on that line , may be they are null or something

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out how to debug it step by step. Still did not solve the problem, but I am narrowing it down.